# Strong cardinals and reflection

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I'm new to all this large cardinal thing and I have trouble in proving the following:

If $\kappa$ is a $\gamma$-strong cardinal, for some large enough $\gamma$, then $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_2$-reflecting.

Any ideas or hints will be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What precisely is the definition of "reflecting" that you are using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A cardinal $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_2$ reflecting if whenever a sentence $\varphi$ is true in some $V_\alpha$, then there is an $\alpha\lt\kappa$ such that $V_\alpha\models\varphi$.

(This can be seen to be equivalent to the "reflecting" version of $\Sigma_2$-reflecting, since every $\Sigma_2$ statement $\psi$ is equivalent to a statement of the form "$\exists\alpha V_\alpha\models\varphi$", where $\varphi$ is some sentence (with no bound on the complexity of $\varphi$). But let us leave this aside.)

Now, if $\kappa$ is a strong cardinal, and there is some $\alpha$ above $\kappa$ such that $V_\alpha\models\varphi$ for some statement $\varphi$, then fix an $\alpha$-strongness embedding $j:V\to M$ with critical point $\kappa$. Since $V_\alpha^M=V_\alpha$, the model $M$ thinks there is $\alpha\lt j(\kappa)$ for which $V_\alpha\models\varphi$. Thus, by elementarity, there is $\alpha\lt\kappa$ in $V$ for which $V_\alpha\models \varphi$, thereby verifying that $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_2$-reflecting, as desired.

Now, to answer your question, pick any $\gamma\gt\kappa$ such that all $\Sigma_2$ statements reflect from $V$ down to $V_\gamma$. Such a cardinal $\gamma$ exists by the Reflection theorem. Now, I claim that any $\gamma$-strong cardinal $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_2$ reflecting, since any statement $\varphi$ true in some $V_\alpha$ will be true in some $V_\alpha$ with $\alpha\lt\gamma$ by the choice of $\gamma$, and thus $\varphi$ will be true in $V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\lt\kappa$ by the argument of the previous paragraph.

In fact, it is easy to see that if $\kappa$ is $\gamma$-strong for this $\gamma$, then in fact it is fully strong, since any violation of strongness of $\kappa$ above $\gamma$ would be reflected below $\gamma$.

Comment: Joel, did you mean $V_\kappa$ on the first line (where describing reflection)?

Comment: @Asaf: No, it is as stated: $\Sigma_2$-reflection means every $\Sigma_2$ (true) fact holds of $V_\kappa$. As Joel mentioned, any such fact has the form: "$\exists\alpha V_\alpha\models\phi$" for some $\phi$ (this requires a proof, of course, but let's assume it is known). That it holds of $V_\kappa$ means then that $V_\kappa$ thinks that there is some $\alpha<\kappa$ with $V_\alpha\models\phi$. But this is just the same as saying that there is an $\alpha<\kappa$ with $V_\alpha\models\phi$.

Comment: @Andres: So if $V_\kappa$ thinks that $\varphi$ reflects down at $\alpha$ then it actually does, or is it vice versa?

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!